# Why after successful ajax call , it does not return to success function

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax

**Ajax call**

```
var wishlistForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
wishlistForm.submitAjaxWishlist = function(button, url,id){
    if(this.validator) {
        var nv = Validation.methods;
        delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
        delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
        delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
        if (this.validator.validate()) {
            url = url.replace("wishlist/index","inquiry/index/index");
            var data = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').serialize();
            data += '&isAjax=1';
            jQuery.ajax( {
                url : url,
                dataType : 'json',
                type : 'post',
                data : data,
                success : function(data) {

                    if(data.status == 'ERROR'){
                        alert(data.message);
                    }else{
                        alert(data.message);
                        window.location = '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'inquiry/index/index'; ?>';

                      /*  alert(data.message);
                        if(jQuery('.block-wishlist').length){
                            jQuery('.block-wishlist').replaceWith(data.sidebar);
                        }else{
                            if(jQuery('.col-right').length){
                                jQuery('.col-right').prepend(data.sidebar);
                            }
                        }
                        if(jQuery('.header .links').length){
                            jQuery('.header .links').replaceWith(data.toplink);
                        }*/
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
    }
}.bind(wishlistForm);
</script>
```

**Function called**

```
 public function indexAction()
    {
        if($this->getRequest()->getParam("isAjax")){

        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer, true); 

                /*echo "<pre>";print_r($this->getRequest()->getParams());die;*/
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam("product"));
            $buyRequest = new Varien_Object($this->getRequest()->getParam("options")); 
            $result = $wishlist->addNewItem($product, $buyRequest);
            $wishlist->save();
            return;
        } 

}
```

Comment: try `return $wishlist->save();`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in your controller

```
public function indexAction()
{
   $response = array();
   try {
       if ($this->getRequest()->getParam("isAjax")) {

            $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
            $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer, true); 

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam("product"));
            $buyRequest = new Varien_Object($this->getRequest()->getParam("options")); 
            $result = $wishlist->addNewItem($product, $buyRequest);
            $wishlist->save();
            $response['status'] = 'SUCCESS';            
            $response['message'] = 'Success Message';            
        }
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $response['status'] = 'ERROR';            
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
}
```